# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addnumber(element){
  document.getElementById(`mvar`).value = document.getElementById(`mvar`).value+element.value;
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <form action="" method="" name="vform">
    <input id=mvar type="text" value="" name="mvar"/><br/>
    <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick=addNumber(this);/>
    <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="2" value="2" id="2" onClick=addNumber(this);/>
    <input type="button" class="fbutton" name="3" value="3" id="3" onClick=addNumber(this);/>
```

What am I missing, or where am I missing something? I

Comment: `onClick=addNumber(this);` you need to add quotes around `addNumber(this);`, right now the `/` of the tag close is understood as part of the onClick attribute.

Comment: Whatsup with back ticks?

Comment: @Aaron quotes are optional

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, but then you'd need a space

Comment: Also, [backticks are ok in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) although there's no reason to use them here

Comment: @Aaron nop, not required https://jsfiddle.net/jnny69kf/

Comment: `addNumber` function name is case-sensitive

Comment: @Mr.Alien: You're not paying close enough attention to the problem in the question: https://jsfiddle.net/jnny69kf/1/

Comment: @Mr.Alien self-closing tags in HTML are pointless. In this case, the HTML parser will think that the `/` character is part of the attribute value.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/z1dnuchh/

Comment: @squint thanks, but I was only pointing out that you don't need quotes around html attr values - https://jsfiddle.net/jnny69kf/2/

Comment: @Pointy yes, missed that part, that he is having self-closing tags which was causing issue, apart from the function name obviously.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Except that Aaron was correct in stating that you'd then need a space, to which you replied *"nop, not required"*. You're correct that quotes are optional, but there are some limitations.

Comment: @squint aah, I think I was not clear enough, what I meant about space was after `=` operator.. between attributes, yea you do

Comment: @Mr.Alien I wasn't so clear myself, sorry. It's not about between attributes, it's between the unquoted last attribute and the tag's `/>` : `onClick=something />` works, so does `onClick="something"/>`, but `onClick=something/>` fails because the `/` (at least) is parsed as part of the attribute's value, which leads to the error in the title. This might depend on the browser used to display the page though.

Comment: @Aaron pretty clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the case-sensitive function name. Also, as Pointy points out (pun intended), the `onClick` had to be in quotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNumber(element){
        var myVar = document.getElementById('mvar');
        myVar.value = myVar.value + element.value;
    }
</script>

<form action="" method="" name="vform">
<input id="mvar" type="text" value="" name="mvar"/><br/>
<input type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick="addNumber(this);" />
<input type="button" class="fbutton" name="2" value="2" id="2" onClick="addNumber(this);" />
<input type="button" class="fbutton" name="3" value="3" id="3" onClick="addNumber(this);" />
```

Comment: @HristoYankov you fixed the problem by putting quotes around the "onClick" attribute value.

Comment: The function name case mismatch was also a problem and would be the next exception his code will throw.

Comment: @HristoYankov, the case mismatch!